# how can I make middleware with svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Where can I find doc about svelte middleware ?

I can not find in https://svelte.dev/docs .

Should I make it by myself? or use 3rd party packages?

Answer (score 3):

Svelte itself is the barebone compiler library, it has no routing/request handling.

SvelteKit can provide a middlewares [via adapters](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters), e.g. the `@svetlejs/adapter-node` [outputs a `handler.js`](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-node#custom-server) which can be used as middleware.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So it is mistake to think Svelte as a framework. it is just a library and that is why it is so fast. I see. thanks.

Comment: Svelte itself is not a framework, yes, but it is fast because it has an optimized update mechanism and does not use something like virtual DOM.